# segmented control give a number value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control and when the user selects the first segment I want it to pass the number 0, second segment 1, and third segment 2. So that I later can do like this:

```
NSString *submitFormJS = [NSString   
stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('usertype').value='**%@**';", **segment**];
```

where the segment is equal to the number: 0, 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UISegmentedControl` has a property named `selectedSegmentIndex` that you *might* find useful for this.

Comment: I have used that, but I cant put selectedSegmentIndex in the string.

Comment: You need to use an integer type (e.g., `%ld`) in your format string instead of `%@`.

Comment: That worked! I just had to add: (long)self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex and switch to %ld. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just use `%d` and you don’t need the `(long)` cast anymore. It’s a `NSInteger`, so you could also just use `%i`.